# Bing Map V8 Infobox Visible not working

Tags: maps, bing-maps

Example from [Bing map V8 official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750644.aspx). By default infobox is given false but inspite its displaying for the first time.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type='text/javascript'
                src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var map, clusterLayer, infobox;

        function GetMap() {
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
                credentials: 'Bing Map Key'
            });

            //Add an infobox to the map.
            infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), { visible: false });
            infobox.setMap(map);

            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.Clustering", function () {
                //Create a clustering layer
                clusterLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(createCustomPushpins(100), {
                    clusteredPinCallback: createCustomClusterPushpins,
                    callback: createPushpinList
                });
                map.layers.insert(clusterLayer);
            });
        }

        function createCustomPushpins(size) {
            //Generate random pushpins within the map bounds.
            var pins = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPushpins(size, map.getBounds());

            for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                //Create a title for each pushpin.
                pins[i].setOptions({ title: 'Pushpin #' + i });

                //Add handler for the pushpin click event.
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pins[i], 'click', pushpinClicked);
            }

            return pins;
        }

        function createCustomClusterPushpins(cluster) {
            //Create a title for the cluster.
            cluster.setOptions({
                title: 'Cluster of ' + cluster.containedPushpins.length + ' pins'
            });

            //Add handler for the cluster click event.
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(cluster, 'click', pushpinClicked);
        }

        function pushpinClicked(e) {
            //Show an infobox when a pushpin is clicked.
            showInfobox(e.target);
        }

        function createPushpinList() {
            //Create a list of displayed pushpins each time clustering layer updates.

            if (clusterLayer != null) {
                infobox.setOptions({ visible: false });

                //Get all pushpins that are currently displayed.
                var data = clusterLayer.getDisplayedPushpins();
                var output = [];

                //Create a list of links for each pushpin that opens up the infobox for it.
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    output.push("<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='showInfoboxByGridKey(", data[i].gridKey, ");'>");
                    output.push(data[i].getTitle(), "</a><br/>");
                }

                document.getElementById('listOfPins').innerHTML = output.join('');
            }
        }

        function showInfoboxByGridKey(gridKey) {
            //Look up the cluster or pushpin by gridKey.
            var clusterPin = clusterLayer.getClusterPushpinByGridKey(gridKey);

            //Show an infobox for the cluster or pushpin.
            showInfobox(clusterPin);
        }

        function showInfobox(pin) {
            var description = [];

            //Check to see if the pushpin is a cluster.
            if (pin.containedPushpins) {

                //Create a list of all pushpins that are in the cluster.
                description.push('<div style="max-height:75px;overflow-y:auto;"><ul>');
                for (var i = 0; i < pin.containedPushpins.length; i++) {
                    description.push('<li>', pin.containedPushpins[i].getTitle(), '</li>');
                }
                description.push('</ul></div>');
            }

            //Display an infobox for the pushpin.
            infobox.setOptions({
                title: pin.getTitle(),
                location: pin.getLocation(),
                description: description.join(''),
                visible: true
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myMap" style="position:relative; width:600px; height:400px;"></div>
        <br />
        <div id="listOfPins" style="max-height:250px;width:250px;overflow-y:scroll;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

As per official documentation, we have to pass visible false while instantiating the infobox object (**infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), { visible: false });**) Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Strange, just tried the code provided in IE11, Edge, Chrome and Firefox. It worked correctly in all browsers other than Chrome. Not sure why Chrome is acting differently. Will have the team look into this. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: is there any event to identify the cluster which cant be dig in as the multiple pushpins are at same lat and long

Comment: When creating the clustered pushpins, check the zoom level. If the map is fully zoomed in, then the clustered pushpin you are creating will no be able to break apart as you are fully zoomed in.

Comment: @rbrundritt any Fix on this?

Comment: The Bing Maps platform is in a code freeze for the month of December due to the peak holiday season. Most of our customers are in a code freeze as well, so we can't push out any updates this month. The team is also working on a number of large tasks at the moment. The plan is to investigate this in January.

Comment: Good news, this is now resolved in the experimental branch. This fix will be in the next update to the release branch which will likely be in February.